# PHP Catchable fatal error

Tags: php

I'm trying to work with web service in PHP with wsdl2php but can't get it done. The generated client code of web service and the result is:

```
class CreateProfile {

  public $firstname;
  public $email;
  public $lastname;
  public $mobile;
  public $password;
  public $provider;
  public $uniqueID;
  public $username;
}

class CreateProfileResponse {

  public $CreateProfileResult;
}

class Profile_WebService extends SoapClient {

  private static $classmap = array(

  'CreateProfile' => 'CreateProfile',
  'CreateProfileResponse' => 'CreateProfileResponse',
);

public function Profile_WebService($wsdl = "http://domain/wcfservice/Profile.WebService.asmx?WSDL", $options = array()) {
foreach(self::$classmap as $key => $value) {
  if(!isset($options['classmap'][$key])) {
    $options['classmap'][$key] = $value;
  }
}
parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
}


public function CreateProfile(CreateProfile $parameters) {
  return $this->__soapCall('CreateProfile', array($parameters),       array(
          'uri' => 'http://domain/',
          'soapaction' => ''
         )
     );
  }

}
```

I want to use that like this:

```
$client = new Profile_WebService();
$client->CreateProfile(array('provider' => 'ENERGIZER','username' => 'ENGtest1','password' => '1369','uniqueId' => '102030405062'));
```

but it keeps saying:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to Profile_WebService::CreateProfile() must be an instance of CreateProfile, array given, called.
```

Could you please enlighten me?

Comment: You must pass a CreateProfile object not an array.  It says it all in the error!  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a new class instance of CreateProfile:

```
$createProfile = new CreateProfile();
```

assign vars to it:

```
$createProfile->firstname = 'Fred';
$createProfile->email = 'test@example.com';
...
...
```

Then pass that object into your method:

```
$client = new Profile_WebService();
$client->CreateProfile($createProfile);
```

Comment: Marshall, thanks for reply but its said PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function CreateProfile() on a non-object.

Comment: don't forget `$client = new Profile_WebService();` before `$client->CreateProfile($createProfile);`

Comment: wow, its works thank you very much, Marshall i dont want to be rude forgive me, can you show me how can i use CreateProfileResponse ?

Comment: the `CreateProfileResponse` class is unfinished it appears so i can't help you there.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateProfile` needs an object, not an array. So this:

```
$client = new Profile_WebService();
$client->CreateProfile(array('provider' => 'ENERGIZER','username' => 'ENGtest1','password' => '1369','uniqueId' => '102030405062'));
```

Can be quickly switched to this:

```
$client = new Profile_WebService();
$CreateProfile_array = array('provider' => 'ENERGIZER','username' => 'ENGtest1','password' => '1369','uniqueId' => '102030405062');
$CreateProfile_object = (object)$CreateProfile_array;
$client->CreateProfile($CreateProfile_object);
```

Comment: needs to be an instance of a specific object, not just an object.

Answer (score 0):

You are telling PHP to expect in the function `CreateProfile()` 1 parameter of the type `CreateProfile`.

But in this line `$client->CreateProfile(array('provider' => 'ENERGIZER','username' => 'ENGtest1','password' => '1369','uniqueId' => '102030405062'));`, you are passing an variable of the type array.

You have to typecast that array to type `object`, like this:

```
$client->CreateProfile((object) array('provider' => 'ENERGIZER','username' => 'ENGtest1','password' => '1369','uniqueId' => '102030405062'));
```